# Resize tensor and interpolate with zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to resize a 2x2 tensor to a 4x4 tensor, but have the new values as zeros.

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4]]
```

becomes

```
[[1,0,2,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [3,0,4,0],
 [0,0,0,0]]
```

I could not find a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a sparse tensor with the values you have and convert it back to dense:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]]) # your input tensor

indices = tf.constant( [[0,0],[0,2],[2,0],[2,2]], dtype=tf.int64 ) # define this as appropriate
values = tf.reshape(a, [-1]) # flatten the input
sparse_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, [4,4])
res = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_tensor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(res))
```

prints

```
array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```